# how to start a project with react as front end and flask as backend?

Tags: reactjs, flask, material-ui

I want to start a project with react as front end and flask as backend and mongodb as my database. How can I connect the react code to the flask code

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Question as it stands is too broad and might be fit for other discussion platforms

Comment: You can find related stuff on google. Stackoverflow is not the place for such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create rest services through flask and then make a request to fetch/insert the data through those services using react.

Comment: can you please tell me how to make that request

Comment: yes ,you can use axios to make a http request i.e
https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-part-3-daa6b31b66be

Comment: @RoshniVidyadharan if the answer is somewhat useful ,kindly accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will wanna take a look at create-react-app that will get you started on the front end. You the wanna build the api using flask and hit those endpoints with the front end to consume the api.

To make the request i recommend using the following
fetch or axios.

While building the api i recommend using postman to see the kind of data you're sending back.

Comment: could you please tell me how to connect them without using axios or fetch,

Comment: is it possible to use flask-restful and flask-cors

Comment: Axios or fetch is just what you use on the front end to send a request to your backend. You can use flask on the backend.